# How to get the printer's DVTARGETDEVICE for implementing Print Preview using ITextHost

Tags: c++, winapi, printing, mfc, ole

I'm still having issues with sizing the CRect (yes, actually using MFC), in addition to drawing the text.

Both the size calculation and the draw implementation needs a DVTARGETDEVICE.  Here's my code:

```
void CRichDrawText::DrawText(CDC& dc, const CRect& rect)
{
  // Draw the text in the windowless control onto the given device context,
  // within the given bounding rectangle.
  //HTRACE("%s w(%d) h(%d)\n", __FUNCTION__, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
  RECTL rc = { rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom };
  LONG lViewID = 0;
  SIZE sPrev;
  bool bUnscale = false;
  if (dc.IsPrinting())
  {
      //lViewID = TXTVIEW_INACTIVE;
      if ((::GetDeviceCaps(dc.m_hDC, TECHNOLOGY) != DT_METAFILE) && (dc.m_hAttribDC != dc.m_hDC))
      {
          VERIFY(::ScaleWindowExtEx(dc.m_hDC,
                                                ::GetDeviceCaps(dc.m_hDC, LOGPIXELSX),
                                                ::GetDeviceCaps(dc.m_hAttribDC, LOGPIXELSX),
                                                ::GetDeviceCaps(dc.m_hDC, LOGPIXELSY),
                                                ::GetDeviceCaps(dc.m_hAttribDC, LOGPIXELSY), &sPrev));
          bUnscale = true;
     }
  }
  HRESULT hr = m_TextServ->TxDraw(DVASPECT_CONTENT,0,NULL,NULL,dc.GetSafeHdc(), bUnscale ? dc.m_hAttribDC : NULL,&rc,NULL,NULL,NULL,0, lViewID);
  if (bUnscale)
  {
      ::SetWindowExtEx(dc.m_hDC, sPrev.cx, sPrev.cy, NULL);
  }
  ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
}
```

It renders great to the screen:
[image: Screen Rendering]

But not when printing to a printer, nor Print Preview.  But it ASSERTs on the Print Preview.  `hr` is equal to `E_INVALIDARG`, I am guessing because I do not provide a DVTARGETDEVICE parameter.

**How do I get the DVTARGETDEVICE?**

I have the MFC CPrintInfo further up the call stack, which I can pass in to the DrawText method, which means I have the PRINTDLG structure.  I'm not an OLE guy, just trying to render Rich Text in my CView derived class (multiple views, split view, all at different zoom levels!)

EDIT - MORE INFO

In the call to TxDraw, if I pass in NULL for the hicTargetDev parm, I no longer get the ASSERT, but then my Print Preview draws according to my Screen, not the printer - no scaling, nothing:
[image]

As I resize the Print Preview window, the RTF text does NOT scale, but everything else properly does.

I know I need to provide the 2nd DC handle, along with info about the Printer (i.e. DVTARGETDEVICE)

MORE INFO:
Well, I found this on Code Project.  There is a method buried in the MFC source that is not publicly available in \Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\olemisc.cpp

`DVTARGETDEVICE* AFXAPI _AfxOleCreateTargetDevice(LPPRINTDLG lpPrintDlg)`

However, the Print Preview is still not scaling.  It's behaving the same.  Here's my current implementation:

```
void CRichDrawText::DrawText(CDC& dc, const CRect& rect, PRINTDLG *pPD, bool bPrintPreview)
{
    // Draw the text in the windowless control onto the given device context,
    // within the given bounding rectangle.
    //HTRACE("%s w(%d) h(%d)\n", __FUNCTION__, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
    RECTL rc = { rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom };
    TXTVIEW eTV = TXTVIEW_ACTIVE;
    SIZE sPrev;
    bool bUnscale = false;

    // print functionality
    DVTARGETDEVICE *pTargetDevice = NULL;
    if (dc.IsPrinting())
    {
        HASSERT(pPD);
        if (pPD && (::GetDeviceCaps(dc.m_hDC, TECHNOLOGY) != DT_METAFILE) && (dc.m_hAttribDC != dc.m_hDC))
        {
            pTargetDevice = ::HEI_AfxOleCreateTargetDevice(pPD);
            if (pTargetDevice)
            {
                VERIFY(::ScaleWindowExtEx(dc.m_hDC,
                    ::GetDeviceCaps(dc.m_hDC, LOGPIXELSX),
                    ::GetDeviceCaps(dc.m_hAttribDC, LOGPIXELSX),
                    ::GetDeviceCaps(dc.m_hDC, LOGPIXELSY),
                    ::GetDeviceCaps(dc.m_hAttribDC, LOGPIXELSY), &sPrev));
                bUnscale = true;
                if (bPrintPreview)
                {
                    eTV = TXTVIEW_INACTIVE;
                }
            }
        }
        HASSERT(bUnscale);
    }

    HRESULT hr = m_TextServ->TxDraw(bUnscale ? DVASPECT_DOCPRINT : DVASPECT_CONTENT, 0, NULL, pTargetDevice, dc.GetSafeHdc(), bUnscale ? dc.m_hAttribDC : NULL, &rc, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, eTV);
    ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    if (bUnscale)
    {
        ::SetWindowExtEx(dc.m_hDC, sPrev.cx, sPrev.cy, NULL);
    }
    if (pTargetDevice != NULL)
        CoTaskMemFree(pTargetDevice);
}
```

This technically compiles and runs, so I should create a new question since I answered this question.

Comment: What's the actual HRESULT returned by the TxDraw method? Sometimes the HRESULT value can give you a hint as to what's wrong.

Comment: `hr` is equal to `E_INVALIDARG`

Comment: Have you tried using DVASPECT_DOCPRINT instead of DVASPECT_CONTENT? Just a wild guess.

Comment: Tried `HRESULT hr = m_TextServ->TxDraw(bUnscale ? DVASPECT_DOCPRINT : DVASPECT_CONTENT,0,NULL,NULL,dc.GetSafeHdc(), bUnscale ? dc.m_hAttribDC : NULL, &rc,NULL,NULL,NULL,0, lViewID);` but got ASSERT with `hr` still equaling `E_INVALIDARG`.

Comment: Does it work right if you just draw lines with standard GDI functions? What mapping mode do you use?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Yes.  The issue is rendering RTF via IText API.  Please see the Print Preview example of the output where lines and normal text are drawn and scaled properly.  Also, the screen rendering of the RTF and lines and normal draw text work great.  See the example where I have 2 views, one of which is a split view, all of the same document, but at different zoom levels.  The app adjusts the RTF generation based on the user's selected zoom level.  This works great for screen, but not for Print Preview, and not for Printer.

Comment: AFAIK nothing "gives" you a `DVTARGETDEVICE`, this is a structure you create yourself using the information returned in the `PRINTDLG` structure after a call to `PrintDlg()`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter What PrintDlg() method do I use to fill in the DVTARGETDEVICE?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to create a DVTARGETDEVICE via _AfxOleCreateTargetDevice (see MORE INFO: question edit above), but the Print Preview still does not work.